# key_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer when installing @react-native-community/masked-view

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to run an `expo install @react-native-community/masked-view` and I get the following error:

> ```
> npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/react-native-community/masked-view.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! key_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
> npm ERR! Connection reset by 140.82.112.3 port 22
> npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository
> ```

Could this be on my end? The VPN I am using perhaps? Could it be that I am not logged in to Git from this machine?

By the way the debug logs did not offer any additional info, same exact info as terminal error.

Comment: yup this is an issue on your end. may be vpn related. you don't need to be signed in to git for this. it's also unclear to me why this would be trying to install from github, perhaps there is some npm config on your end doing this? the masked-view library is published to npm and github should not be involved whatsoever

Comment: @brentvatne, I do not have an `npm config` to do this. Everything else I installed grabbed from `npm` repository. You can see how I ran the command in the OP, just as it says in their docs.

Comment: `expo install package-name` just runs `npm install package-name` and appends a version to the end. so, try running `npm install @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10` to get the same result as what `expo install` does for you. when you observe that you can then see clearly that something is wrong with your npm install/config or network, because such a command certainly should work.

Comment: @brentvatne, okay, I already did run `npm install @react-native-community/masked-view`. I thought that was was somehow different from `expo install` package of same name. I should be good then.